edit reason declined with reason "comment reserved for system use"
EDIT: This bug seems cross-site and has been reported elsewhere (1) and (2), too.
When editing this question by replacing the supplied images of the formula with identical mathjax formulas I tried to supply a reason as shown in the image with "use mathjax instead of images". However that edit reason was declined by the system with a message of

Comment reserved for system use. Please use an appropriate comment."


I actually tried a few variations of the shown comment, but none was satisfactorily until I deleted the edit reason and left it blank.
Giving an edit reason is not mandatory, but might sometimes be desirable. However I wonder whether I miss here something?
If not, I'd like to suggest to change this check so that usual reasons can be given and differentiate system reasons (if needed) differently.
Lol. And when reviewing this very question here in meta I got a 404 when hitting the "post question" button. Something seems to be fishy right now.

Resolved on this MSE post
